# Transparent cube when stacked together face to face, the faces are darker

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, unity

I have been working on a game in unity. Everything was going smoothly until i hit this problem. I wanted to give a water effect, so I made a  cube and set its alpha to 3.5 in material -> transparency.

When I stack them in Unity I do get transparent water like effect that i want but the faces gets so much darker that it ruins the effect.

Any method to make the faces of the same light colour too? because these cubes will spawn every second and if they give that dark look it ruins the effect i am going for.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Blender Settings]

[image: What I am getting in unity]

Comment: Computer software in general doesn't deal well overlapping geometry

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos but they arent overlapping. they are put side by side.

Comment: if they are 1*1*1 cubes, one is at 0,0,0 and other is at 1,0,0. still that dark face in between